# How to debug custom log collection in Log Analytics?

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I set up my log analytics to collect Custom Logs on Windows Server from folder C:\OmsCustomLog but nothing is visible in Log Search (I've been waiting for over hour now).

All configuration was made with this document so I guess this is not an issue (?) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-custom-logs

How to debug it? Is OMS agent even reading this folder? Is file in wrong format? Any way of debugging it?